# How to link to a translated node?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

My Basic Page content type is using field translation, and I create a node (mysite.com/node/1 for English, mysite.com/de/node/1 for German).

Now in the body field of another node, I hyperlink some text to 'node/1'. But if I am viewing the site in German and I click that link, it reverts back to English.

Is the answer to provide a translation for the body field, hyperlinking to 'de/node/1' instead? I guess this would work, but seems like a lot of extra work for content editors?

Or am I missing something easy? I tried using Path Translation module (part of [i18n package](http://drupal.org/project/i18n)), but it doesn't recognise 'de/node/1' as a valid path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, there is a module for that! :) Check out [Multi-Language Link and Redirect (MultiLink)](http://drupal.org/project/multilink). It was a bit buggy when I was testing it 5 months ago so I didn't include it in my [Drupal 7 Multilingual Sites book](http://kristen.org/book) (well, it's referred to in the appendix, page 112), but it should be working by now. Have fun!

Comment: MultiLink module requires core Content Translation to be enabled, and I don't think Content Translation *and* Entity Translation should be enabled together?

Comment: My mistake - they *can* be enabled together :)

Answer (score 2):

As Kristen says, the [MultiLink Filter](http://drupal.org/project/multilink) will address that problem, in fact it was designed specifically to address the issue you describe.  If you have English content at node/1 then the German version **must** be at another node (node/2, whatever.)  So (without using MultiLink) where in English content you include a link to node/1, the German version would have to contain a link to node/2.  That can result in a **lot** of extra work for content editors, as you say.

Another module you might want to investigate is [Language Sections](http://drupal.org/project/language_sections). That provides a way of storing multiple language content in a single node (or any other text field, such as a custom block.)  But it is not a complete solution, since it only deals with text, not other fields such as node title.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Entity Translation (field translation) so both English and German content are in the same node. But I think the linking issues you describe may still apply, as different translations of a node can have different paths with Entity Translation.

Comment: As commented above, MultiLink requires core Content Translation, which is actually replaced by Entity Translation.

Comment: Ah but they can play nicely together, and MultiLink works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Entity Translation, and had good luck with http://drupal.org/project/pathologic.  The project page says there are still some issues with multilingual sites, what I did is stick to linking internal paths only (like /node/1) which is probably the least complex use case, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but Pathologic won't create the correct language paths for me, even when linking internal paths only.

Comment: I should add... Pathologic does create language aware paths for me, but seems confused by the last edited language. If I edit a German translation of a node, all links for every language turn German :\